# How to automatically refuse cookie while executing the powershell invoke-webrequest code below each time?

Tags: powershell

This is the code line I use to request .html links from websites. But every time, it always keep asking me whether to accept or refuse its cookie. That means i ll have to keep attending to the computer while it executes the code. How can i set it to refuse the cookie automatically?

```
$iwr = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $categoryLink).Links.Href
```

Comment: Try adding the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter switch.

Comment: It worked. It also worked while fetching other sources. Thanks a lot!